Build dockerfile without confirming tag each time in VS Code?
In VS Code, one can right click on a Dockerfile, select Build image ... and after that it asks for a tag.
For my developments, I always leave that to "latest", but I have to confirm it each time - quite annoying. How to stop VS Code from asking for the tag each time? I want to define it once, that's it.


If you prefer to stick within VS Code’s UI and not use the terminal (for whatever reason), you can create a tasks.json file that runs the Docker build with a predefined tag.

Open your .vscode folder (create it if it doesn't exist)
Create or edit the tasks.json file inside the .vscode folder and add the following:

{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build Docker Image",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "docker build -t your-image-tag-name:latest .",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}

With this, you can simply trigger the build task (by hitting Cmd+Shift+B on macOS or Ctrl+Shift+B on Windows/Linux), and VS Code will run the docker build -t your-image-name:latest . command without needing to manually execute the command and without asking for a tag.
You can follow the official VS Code docs for detailed information https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference
And here is more about the tasks.json in general https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

You're welcome :D
